# CSS Typed Object Model: Use instance methods of CSSNumericValue with CSS variables

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables, cssom, css-houdini

I'm trying to use the CSS Typed Object Model (CSS Typed OM) API in JavaScript to manipulate CSS values, specifically involving CSS variables within expressions. Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
const x = CSSNumericValue.parse("calc(400px - var(--x))");
const newX = x.add(CSS.px(40));
const strX = newX.toSum().toString() // I expect strX to be "calc(440px - var(--x))" or similar.
```

However, it seems that CSSNumericValue.parse() doesn't accept expressions containing CSS variables, instead it will throw an error stating `Failed to execute 'parse' on 'CSSNumericValue': Invalid math expression`. Is there an alternative way to achieve this functionality, or is there a known solution within the CSS Typed OM API or CSS Houdini project or does anyone have any insights into why this doesn't work?

I could parse the string via `CSSStyleValue.parse("width", "calc(400px - var(--x))")`. But that returns a `CSSUnparsedValue` class which isn't helpful either in this case, since I can't perform math operations on `CSSUnparsedValue`.

I've tried to look for documentation or notes on this topic online and found some information here:

- https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-typed-om/#reify-tokens
- https://github.com/w3c/css-houdini-drafts/issues/208